# Can access display multiline captions in Access 365 form datasheet view?

Tags: forms, ms-access, office365, caption, datasheet

I have read about using VBA to concatenate terms together using VbCrLf; I personally used Ctrl-Enter to create a second line in the caption field in the properties box.

But, after I do my ctrl-enter, it then only shows the first line of my multi-line caption in the datasheet view of my form.

[image]

becomes this...

[image]

This form is meant to recreate the functionality our owner is looking for from a current excel spreadsheet (the ability to sort on various columns), so I can't just use a report.

Please tell me I'm missing something obvious such as a caption height property value or something.  The multiline caption will be very useful to help maintain appropriate column widths for the data.

Comment: Sorry, not possible.

Comment: I'm pretending I didn't see your answer! Ha! In all seriousness, care to elaborate as to why?  It seems odd to allow multiline data in the property and then do nothing with it.

Comment: Can't tell why. It's by design.

Comment: Well, I know I couldn't figure it out.  Maybe someone smarter than us can hack the system.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: Increase the height(size) of your row by resizing it at the row headers. If you click on `Save` in Datasheet view it will save the height adjustment. Unfortunately, I know of no way to display scroll bars, or notify the user visually that there is more data following in the data cell if you happen to have random line counts.

Comment: From what I've tried and read you can't adjust the row headers in a datasheet form view in Access.  It's one of the limitations of the specific "Datasheet" form.  The solution is to create a tabbed form which takes more work but gives you more granular control over your setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution to adjusting column headers in the specific "datasheet" form that I was trying to use.  It's a nice quick way that works for 95% of your uses.  But, if you need more control (like me and others on the internet) the only solution is to create the form as a "Tabular" form in the form wizard.  There are other descriptions of this type of form in Access (just to be confusing).

This is also described as a continuous form likely because that's the form property value toggle when you dive into the details.

It's more work but you have full control over the size, format, etc. of your column headers when creating/designing a tabular form.

Comment: *This is also described as a continuous form* -- that's the official name. Just for future searching purposes.

Comment: Thanks Andre.  That's why I included "continuous form" in my comment above.  I'm new enough I didn't realize they were the same thing until a lot of reading.  Hopefully that's enough to catch a search and lead someone here.  There were enough people asking around the web that it should be useful.  The "datasheet" form is fantastic if you just need a quick continuous form.  But, it didn't take me too long to edit a "tabular" form and I could control/tweak a lot more features fairly easily.

Comment: Actually I meant for *your* future searches. :-) -- I don't think I have seen the term "tabular form" anywhere.

Comment: That's the term used by Access in their Form Wizard.  You can select "Tabular" as one of the options.  It's also how many of the tutorials referred to it.  However, as you say, it's more commonly called "Continuous" and that's what kept coming up as a solution in my internet searches.  "Use a continuous form" only I didn't know what that was!  Now I know.  So that's why I was thinking the other way around for searching.  It took many links to find someone that connected "tabular" and "continuous" so I knew they were essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you can display multiple lines of content within the datasheet view for a table by increasing the row height of each record, e.g.:

[image]

A more appropriate solution might be to use a text box on a form to display the data, where the height of the text box can be predefined in the design of the form, and scroll bars can be displayed:

[image]

Comment: That's good for within the data but not for the headers.